# Reducer states not received because of a Route in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, reducers, react-router-dom

I have a very mysterious dilemma: I'm using Reducers to receive a User model from my backend. At first, the reducer returns a state of null (as expected because it's still pending the API call) and then the User model the second time around.

If that User model exists AND the customer tries to navigate to /setup, then we'll let him -- he's "authenticated". However, if he tries to access /setup and the User model doesn't exist, we redirect him back to the root path ("/").

I've made a function that will called within my App.js's Route element that checks this OAuth, called AuthenticatedRoute.js

When we get the initial value from the reducer (of null), we render the AuthenticatedRoute.js, see the value is null and then navigate to the root path. The problem is, when I get the SECOND value from the reducer (of the user model), the AuthenticatedRoute.js doesn't try to re-render at all. Isn't it suppose to? The state of the prop in App.js (the parent component) changed. It's "suppose" to check so we can check if the User model came back and if the customer is allowed to go to the /setup page.

App.js (parent component that contains the Route):

```
class App extends Component {
    state = { isUserSetUp: false }
    // If User exists AND its isProfileSetUp is true then change state to TRUE
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

        if (nextProps.auth && nextProps.auth.isProfileSetUp) {
            this.setState({ isUserSetUp: false }, function() {
                console.log("This is when we receive the User model from the reducer");
            });
        }
        else {
            this.setState({ isUserSetUp: false });     
        }

    }
    // Upon mount of this component, we receive the User via a reducer endpoint
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchUser();
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="container">
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <div>
                        <Header />
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
                        <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />

                        {/* Profile Set up... This is using our AuthenticatedRoute*/}
                        <Route exact path="/setup" component={AuthenticatedRoute(Setup, this.state.isUserSetUp, Landing)} />
                    </div>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```

And here is the AuthenticatedRoute:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

export default function requireAuth(Component, isAuthenticated, Landing) {

  class AuthenticatedComponent extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount() {
      this.checkAuth();
    }
    // We call this only the first time...never the second time around
    checkAuth() {
      console.log("This is when we run the AuthenticatedRoute");
      if (!isAuthenticated) {

        // For some reason when this hits, I no longer get the second value (User model) from the reducer. WITHOUT it, I get the second value in this component.
        this.props.history.push('/');

      }
    }

    render() {
      return isAuthenticated
        ? <Component { ...this.props } />
        : null;
    }

  }

  return withRouter(AuthenticatedComponent);
}
```

NOTE:
So without the "this.props.history.push('/') within the AuthenticatedRoute, I RECEIVE the second reducer response (I tried console.logging it from the AuthenticatedRoute's render() method)...But the moment I handle the reducer's first response with the this.props.history.push, I never get the second response.

Same deal if I use a  within the:

```
render() {
   return isAuthenticated
      ? <Component { ...this.props } />
      : null;
}
```

Do you guys have any idea? This is too weird.